# Angular Object - Pass the selected value to another variable

Tags: angular

I am trying to set a variable of type number to the selected value of an object but do not understand how to set it.

I want to get the age of the selected cat.  I want the `selectAge` to be an integer but it is displayed as NaN

HTML:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
  <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled>Select An Option</option>
  <option *ngFor="let o of options" [ngValue]="o.age">Name: {{o.name}}</option>
</select>
```

COMPONENT:

```
selectedOption: any; 
  options = [
    { name: "Neeko", age: 4},
    { name: "Gato", age: 6},
    { name: "Gatto", age: 12}
  ]

  // This is the problem. How do I correct it?
  // selectAge: number = +this.selectedOption; //NaN
```

Comment: How could the user possibly have selected any value, and thus set the `selectedOption` value, while you haven't even finished constructing your component yet, and the component is thus not displayed in the browser yet? The line `selectAge: number = +this.selectedOption;` is executed when constructing the component. Since you haven't initialized the property `selectedOption`, its value is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for instance your selectedOption variable is Null, so you are getting this error. You can use ngModelChange event to bind it.

In your html file

```
<select (ngModelChange) = "dataChanged($event)" [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
  <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled>Select An Option</option>
  <option *ngFor="let o of options" [ngValue]="o.age">Name: {{o.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Ts file

```
selectAge: number = 0;
dataChanged($event){
    this.selectAge = +this.selectedOption
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ngModelChange` event on your `<select>` directive. When your selection changes, Angular will call the `ngModelChange` and then you will be able to assign your value:

HTML:

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption" (ngModelChange)="onValueChanged($event)">
  <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled>Select An Option</option>
  <option *ngFor="let o of options" [ngValue]="o.age">Name: {{o.name}}</option>
</select>
```

The `$event` variable represents the selected option.

```
export class AppComponent {
  selectedOption: any; 
  options = [
    { name: "Neeko", age: 4},
    { name: "Gato", age: 6},
    { name: "Gatto", age: 12}
  ];

  public onValueChanged(selected: any): void {
    this.selectedOption = selected;
    console.log(this.selectedOption); // should display the selected option.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look at this demo code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-angular-mennsu?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

```
<select [(ngModel)] ="selected" name="valueCheck" (change)="valueChange($event)"> 
  <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled>Select Any </option>
  <option *ngFor="let obj of stud" 
        [ngValue]="obj.age" [selected]="obj.age == selected"> 
            {{obj.name}} 
  </option>
</select>
```

with `ts` code on `(change)` event

```
valueChange(event) {
 this.selectAge = +this.selected;
}
```